# react navigation dependencies trouble

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following error when installing react navigation dependencies, I don't know if to force it since it tells me that it can bring errors. It is echoed with `npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript`.

[image]

Comment: Can you try to install those packages using `expo` instead of `npm` directly? I think that will help you.